# Einstein-Convention like implicit summation with sympy

Tags: sympy

Given some simpy tensor

```
A = sympy.tensor.array.Array( <3rd-rank data consisting of sympy expressions> )
```

and a matrices `T` and `T1=T.inv()` representing a basis transform, is it somehow possible to use an notation like

```
B[i,j,k] = T[i,a] * A[a,b,c] * T1[b,j] * T1[c,k]
```

to calculate the transformed tensor?

It seems that it is, in principle, possible in sympy to use an Einstein summation convention, but I am running into multiple problems with it:

- A code snippet

  ```
  from sympy import symbols, IndexedBase, EinsteinSum 
  TX, A, x = symbols('TX A x', cls=IndexedBase)
  i, j = symbols('i j')
  ein_sum = EinsteinSum(A[i, j] * x[j])
  ```

  I found doesn't work, because `EinsteinSum` doesn't seem to exist anymore.
- When trying to use expressions like

  ```
  var("i")
  Sum(A[i,i,i],(i,1,3))
  ```

  I will raise a TypeError (apparently `Array` doesn't allow symbolic indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some features have been recently added to the [development version](https://github.com/sympy/sympy) of SymPy. They will be available in the next version.

**NOTE:** `EinsteinSum` has never existed. There was just a proposal to add it, IIRC.

Let's suppose you have 3-rank array `A` given by

```
In [13]: A
Out[13]: 
⎡⎡1  0  0   0 ⎤  ⎡0   0   0  1⎤  ⎡0   0  0  -ⅈ⎤  ⎡0   0  1  0 ⎤⎤
⎢⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥⎥
⎢⎢0  1  0   0 ⎥  ⎢0   0   1  0⎥  ⎢0   0  ⅈ  0 ⎥  ⎢0   0  0  -1⎥⎥
⎢⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥⎥
⎢⎢0  0  -1  0 ⎥  ⎢0   -1  0  0⎥  ⎢0   ⅈ  0  0 ⎥  ⎢-1  0  0  0 ⎥⎥
⎢⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥  ⎢            ⎥⎥
⎣⎣0  0  0   -1⎦  ⎣-1  0   0  0⎦  ⎣-ⅈ  0  0  0 ⎦  ⎣0   1  0  0 ⎦⎦
```

and a simple matrix `T` given by:

```
In [15]: T
Out[15]: 
⎡2  0  0  0⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  2  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  0  2  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣0  0  0  2⎦
```

So that:

```
In [17]: T.inv()
Out[17]: 
⎡1/2   0    0    0 ⎤
⎢                  ⎥
⎢ 0   1/2   0    0 ⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎢ 0    0   1/2   0 ⎥
⎢                  ⎥
⎣ 0    0    0   1/2⎦
```

I suggest to convert everything to `Array` as I fear that Matrix and Array objects won't interoperate that well.

Symbolic indices are now supported:

```
In [28]: T[i, j]
Out[28]: 
⎡2  0  0  0⎤      
⎢          ⎥      
⎢0  2  0  0⎥      
⎢          ⎥[i, j]
⎢0  0  2  0⎥      
⎢          ⎥      
⎣0  0  0  2⎦
```

As soon as the values *i* and *j* are replaced with numbers, the tensor expression will be evaluated.

If you want to operate on tensor products of arrays, use the `tensorproduct` and `tensorcontraction` functions. To emulate the matrix multiplication on Array objects:

```
In [29]: tensorcontraction(tensorproduct(T, T1), (1, 2))
Out[29]: 
⎡1  0  0  0⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  1  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  0  1  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣0  0  0  1⎦
```

**NOTE:** the latest SymPy version has a bug with `tensorcontraction` if contracting on many axes at the same time. Development branch should be solved.

The expression `Sum(A[i,i,i],(i, 0, 3))` works (**NOTE:** start index from 0, not 1 in Python).

The expression `Sum(T[i, j]*T1[j, k], (j, 0, 3))` does not give a nice result, as it does not understand what to simplify. Compare:

```
In [38]: Sum(T[i, j]*T1[j, k], (j, 0, 3))
Out[38]: 
  3                                                 
______                                              
╲                                                   
 ╲     ⎡1/2   0    0    0 ⎤       ⎡2  0  0  0⎤      
  ╲    ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥      
   ╲   ⎢ 0   1/2   0    0 ⎥       ⎢0  2  0  0⎥      
    ╲  ⎢                  ⎥[j, k]⋅⎢          ⎥[i, j]
    ╱  ⎢ 0    0   1/2   0 ⎥       ⎢0  0  2  0⎥      
   ╱   ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥      
  ╱    ⎣ 0    0    0   1/2⎦       ⎣0  0  0  2⎦      
 ╱                                                  
╱                                                   
‾‾‾‾‾‾                                              
j = 0
```

If you evaluate it, you get:

```
In [39]: Sum(T[i, j]*T1[j, k], (j, 0, 3)).doit()
Out[39]: 
⎡1/2   0    0    0 ⎤       ⎡2  0  0  0⎤         ⎡1/2   0    0    0 ⎤       ⎡2  0  0  0⎤         ⎡1/2   0    0    0 ⎤       ⎡2  0  0  0⎤   
⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥         ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥         ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥   
⎢ 0   1/2   0    0 ⎥       ⎢0  2  0  0⎥         ⎢ 0   1/2   0    0 ⎥       ⎢0  2  0  0⎥         ⎢ 0   1/2   0    0 ⎥       ⎢0  2  0  0⎥   
⎢                  ⎥[0, k]⋅⎢          ⎥[i, 0] + ⎢                  ⎥[1, k]⋅⎢          ⎥[i, 1] + ⎢                  ⎥[2, k]⋅⎢          ⎥[i,
⎢ 0    0   1/2   0 ⎥       ⎢0  0  2  0⎥         ⎢ 0    0   1/2   0 ⎥       ⎢0  0  2  0⎥         ⎢ 0    0   1/2   0 ⎥       ⎢0  0  2  0⎥   
⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥         ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥         ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥   
⎣ 0    0    0   1/2⎦       ⎣0  0  0  2⎦         ⎣ 0    0    0   1/2⎦       ⎣0  0  0  2⎦         ⎣ 0    0    0   1/2⎦       ⎣0  0  0  2⎦   

      ⎡1/2   0    0    0 ⎤       ⎡2  0  0  0⎤      
      ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥      
      ⎢ 0   1/2   0    0 ⎥       ⎢0  2  0  0⎥      
 2] + ⎢                  ⎥[3, k]⋅⎢          ⎥[i, 3]
      ⎢ 0    0   1/2   0 ⎥       ⎢0  0  2  0⎥      
      ⎢                  ⎥       ⎢          ⎥      
      ⎣ 0    0    0   1/2⎦       ⎣0  0  0  2⎦
```

which is the correct result, but the representation is not nice-looking. SymPy fails to recognize the possible simplifications that may occur.

To get back a matrix in a nice form, you could use:

```
In [45]: Matrix([[Sum(T[i, j]*T1[j, k], (j, 0, 3)).doit().subs({i: ni, k: nk}) for ni in range(4)] for nk in range(4)])
Out[45]: 
⎡1  0  0  0⎤
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  1  0  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎢0  0  1  0⎥
⎢          ⎥
⎣0  0  0  1⎦
```