# Sympy: Specific expression from tensor

Tags: sympy, symbolic-math

I'm struggling with the following problem (which might be exarcerbated by the fact that I'm both not quite familiar with sympy and tensors yet, so please bear with me, especially if I'm off on terminology).

I have:

An n-dim array/tensor of order n, Q,  with dimensions ( v1, v2, ... vn)

A total of n vectors a, b, c ..., their length corresponding to the dimensions (a has length v1 and so on).

I'm looking for an expression for

[sum_ijk... (a_i * b_j *c_k ... Q_ijk...)](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Csum_%7Bijk...%7D%20a_i%20b_j%20c_k%20...%20Q_%7Bijk...%7D)

The expression should be valid for any n>2, where n is a known integer.

(Another way to put it: I basically want a generalisation of a'Qb, assuming Q is a matrix, and a and b column vectors of appropriate length.)

I feel like this should be relatively simple using tensor products/contractions, but somehow I'm stuck getting what I want.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907090/einstein-convention-like-implicit-summation-with-sympy) might be of interest.